# After sorting by mean, how to sort by highest minimum

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, min

I have a pandas dataframe with columns=usernames rows=restaurant names.  The values are ratings given by users.  Then sorted by mean.  E.g.:

```
ratings = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 4], [5, 8], [7, 9], [3, 4], [8, 8], [6, 7], [5, 2], [4, 9]], 
                        index=['rest1', 'rest2', 'rest3', 'rest4', 'rest5', 'rest6', 'rest7', 'rest8'], 
                        columns=[user1, user2])

ratings_sorted = preds_db.sort_values(by='mean', ascending=False)
```

Now, in the case of a tie, I want the restaurant with the *higher minimum values for both users* to be ranked higher. For example, rest2, rest6, and rest8 all have mean values of 6.5, but I want them ranked like: rest6 > rest2 > rest8, since rest6=(6, 7), rest2=(5, 8), rest8=(4,9).

My plan was to make a new list with the restaurants resorted and use that as the new index.  Here's my super messy attempt:

```
def highest_min(rest1, rest2, db):
    if db.loc[rest1].min() > db.loc[rest2].min():
        return [rest1, rest2]
    return [rest2, rest1]

def add_resorted_column(preds_db_sorted):
    resorted = []
    for i, rest in enumerate(preds_db_sorted.index):
        if i < len(preds_db_sorted.index)-1:
            if preds_db_sorted.iloc[i]['mean'] != preds_db_sorted.iloc[i+1]['mean']:
                if preds_db_sorted.index[i] not in resorted:
                    resorted.append(rest)
            else:
                resorted.extend(highest_min(
                            preds_db_sorted.index[i], 
                            preds_db_sorted.index[i+1], 
                            preds_db_sorted))
        else: 
            if preds_db_sorted.index[-1] not in resorted:
                resorted.append(preds_db_sorted.index[-1]) 
    return resorted
```

I know there's gotta be a better way out there.  Also, this has the problem of producing duplicates when there are more than two restaurants in a tie.  In addition, I'd like to scale this to work for more than two users.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just using `mean` and `min` with `concat` and sort them together

```
idx=pd.concat([ratings.mean(1),ratings.min(1)],axis = 1).\
        sort_values([0,1],ascending=[True,False]).\
             index
ratings.loc[idx]
       user1  user2
rest1      1      4
rest4      3      4
rest7      5      2
rest6      6      7
rest2      5      8
rest8      4      9
rest5      8      8
rest3      7      9
ratings=ratings.loc[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    ratings = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 4], [5, 8], [7, 9], [3, 4], [8, 8], [6, 7], [5, 2], [4, 9]], 
                            index=['rest1', 'rest2', 'rest3', 'rest4', 'rest5', 'rest6', 'rest7', 'rest8'], 
                            columns=['user1', 'user2'])
    ratings['mean']=ratings.mean(axis=1)
    ratings['min']=ratings.min(axis=1)
    ratings_sorted = ratings.sort_values(by=['mean','min'], ascending=False)
    print(ratings_sorted)
```